# Boostrap-Select Get Latest Chosen Option on Change Event

Tags: jquery

I have this select dropdown menu and I am using Bootstrap-select:

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

```
<select id="properties" name="properties[]" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
</select>

$( document ).ready(function() {

  // instantiating the main properties
  loadProperties(0);

$('#properties').on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    alert(optionSelected.data('parent'));
});

});

function loadProperties(param) {
  var propSelect = $('#properties');

  $.get("json/" + param + ".json",function(options,status){
    $.each(options, function(val, text) {
      var option = $('<option data-parent="' + param + '" class="prop-option"></option>').val(val).html(text);
      propSelect.append(option);
    });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  });
}
```

The problem is that I need to get the last option selected and NOT every selected option. 
I can only use the on change method because Bootstrap-select does not return any click event on the options.

How can I get only the last chosen option using the on Change event?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : you can store last selected option as some `data` attribute, lets say `data-prev` and update it for every `change` event. See below code -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // instantiating the main properties
  loadProperties(0);

  $('#properties').on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    //read last selected value
    var lastSelected = $(this).data('prev');
    alert(lastSelected);
    //update last selected value
    $(this).data('prev',optionSelected.data('parent'));
    alert(optionSelected.data('parent'));
  });

});
```

Comment: It does not work ;( It does not add the new data attribute at all

Comment: If you are checking data attribute in DOM inspector then it will not be visible, you have to use `.attr('data-prev',val)` instead of `.data('prev',val)`

Comment: I solved the issue just using this:     var parent_id = $("option:selected:last",this).val();